# Redux thunk wont update with response from async function

Tags: reactjs, redux, geolocation, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have been following a guide to setup redux-thunk so I can fetch a users geolocation and then dispatch and update state. However, every time I attempt to dispatch the action with response data, it just sets the data to null.

When I attempt to simulate an API call with a timeout and set some random values, it works without a problem.

geoLocationActions.js

```
export function geoLocationActions() {
   return dispatch => {
    const geolocation = navigator.geolocation;
    geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        console.log(position.coords);
        dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_USER_LOCATION_SUCCESS',
            payload: position
        });
    });
  } 
};
```

MapContainer.js

```
import React from "react";
import { geoLocationActions } from '../../../actions/geoLocationActions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MapContainer extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.geoLocationActions();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Fetching location...</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// update current geolocation state
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        geoLocationActions: () => dispatch(geoLocationActions())
    };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        state: state
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MapContainer);
```

reducers.js

```
case 'FETCH_USER_LOCATION_SUCCESS':
        return {
            ...state,
            userLocation: action.payload
        }
```

store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 

'redux';
import reducer from '../reducers/reducers';
import reduxThunk from "redux-thunk";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    state: reducer
});

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(reduxThunk),
        window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    )
);
```

Comment: Are you seeing the `console.log(position.coords);` in your console?

Comment: yes! Indeed I do, that's why this seems very weird to me.

Comment: Throw a `console.log()` in your reducer. Is that being called? Next, add a `console.log(this.props)` in your render function, is that being called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns an HTML5 Geoposition object. You need to convert it to a regular object that can be serialized with JSON.stringify.
You can use this method:

```
const geopositionToObject = geoposition => ({
  timestamp: geoposition.timestamp,
  coords: {
    accuracy: geoposition.coords.accuracy,
    latitude: geoposition.coords.latitude,
    longitude: geoposition.coords.longitude
  }
})
```

Update your geoLocationActions.js like this:

```
export function geoLocationActions() {
   return dispatch => {
    const geolocation = navigator.geolocation;
    geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        const positionObj = geopositionToObject(position)
        console.log(positionObj);
        dispatch({
            type: 'FETCH_USER_LOCATION_SUCCESS',
            payload: positionObj
        });
    });
  } 
};
```

You can have a look at [my repo](https://github.com/trkaplan/around-me/blob/6500214be8f773799aafd7b275076e30dd646af9/src/utils/geolocation.js) to see the same code.